# storing and securing the video using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04

this is my first question on the site.

Currently I am working on one application which captures the video and store it in the system hard drive. Both the functionality is working fine.We are storing the videos in two different files as left.mp4 and right.mp4 and then we are combining them to one main.mp4 file.

But while recording the video if accidentally the system gets down the both the videos are gets corrupting.
How can I do such that though system is down, video before shutdown gets secured or **how can make secure while recording the video** or **can we store the video in different format to resolve this error**

I am using following ffmpeg command for this

```
 ffmpeg -loglevel warning -y  -i /base_dir/right.mp4 -i /base_dir/left.mp4 -filter_complex '[1:0] pad=1088:288:0:0:black [padvidleft]; [0:0] setpts=PTS+0.5519998073577881/TB [right_cam_pts]; [padvidleft][right_cam_pts] overlay=544:0 [mergedvid] ; [1:2] channelsplit [ll][lr]; [ll][lr] amix [leftmix]; [1:3] channelsplit [rl][rr]; [rl][rr] amix [rightmix];
[leftmix][rightmix] amix [cam_all];[1:4] channelsplit [btl][btr] ; [btl][btr] amix [btmix] ;
[btmix][cam_all] join [bt_mixcam]' -f mp4 -crf 20 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -map [mergedvid] -map [bt_mixcam] -map 1:2 -map 1:3 -map 1:4 /video-output/combos/combo-2013-10-07T22-39-05_1186300d3a8f6e08c67339f6871567f880abf287a855c_1088x288.mp4
```

Is there any command for this or anyone can give me suggestion for resolving this?
I am using ubunutu for this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should use mpeg2ts, it fits better when you have some problems during encoding.

Comment: is not possible using ffmpeg?

Comment: or we can modify the above command?

Comment: can we store the video in different format to resolve this error

Comment: Yes, it's possible with ffmpeg. To use mpeg2ts you should specify "-f mpegts" for output file.

Comment: but I am directly recording the video. so I have same input and output file. can please refer the above command. How can I modify above command so that I can use **mpegts**

Comment: You have not specified full command, so I cant modify it.

Comment: We are using above command for this.

Comment: Command above won't work, there is no even closing comma in filter complex argument.

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly put incomplete command. I have updated it please review it.

Comment: You should just replace "-f mp4" with "-f mpegts" and filename aslo  should end not with .mp4, but with .ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I changed the encoding format from **.mp4 to mpegts** and it works fine.
and in the command we just replace `"-f mp4" with "-f mpegts"`.